Создание сессии Pyrogram без ввода данных в консоль
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно создавать новую сессию Pyrogram для юзер бота, не вводя данные в консоль. Такие способы как sent_code и sign_in после работают лишь тогда, когда сессия уже запущена, то есть существует. Можно ли как-то сделать это так, как я этого хочу, если да, то очень хотел бы узнать как
